# Python NetworkX: How to access edges with a specific data value

Tags: python, networkx

For a bond percolation model I want to build a square lattice with NetworkX using `grid_2d_graph(l,l)`. This gives me a square lattice of size `lxl` with every edge `open`.

The idea is that I want to pick an edge of the graph randomly, then check if the edge has already been assigned (1 to leave the edge as it is, 0 to add it to the list of edges to remove from the graph) and if it hasn't been assigned yet (edge has `'state' = -1`), I want to randomly choose with a specific probability `p`, if the edge is open (leave it as it is), or if it is closed (put it on the list of the edges to remove).

Therefor, I saved all edges with data attribute `'state' = -1` as a list and then tried to randomly access an entry of this list to then change the attribute `'state'` to some value. But it seems that this operation is not allowed. When I try to edit the states, I receive the following error:

```
File "bond-percolation.py", line 39, in <module>
    ed[10][2] = 1
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

So my question is, how can I randomly pick an edge and change the value of `'state'` efficiently?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

#Width of the quadratic lattice
l = 30
#Create grid
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(l,l)
#Total number of edges in the lattice
n = 2 * l * (l-1)
m = 0
#Set probability if an edge is open
p = 0.17
#Create empty list to add closed edges later
ed = []
ld = []

for e in G.edges(data = 'state', default = -1):
    ed.append(e)

#Creating the lattice
while (m != n):
    i = np.random.randint(n-1)
    a = random.random()
    if (ed[i][2] == -1):
        if (a > p):
            ld.append(ed[i])
        else:
            ed[i][2] = 1    
        m = m + 1


#We need this so that the lattice is drawn vertically to the horizon
pos = dict( (l,l) for l in G.nodes() )

#Draw the lattice
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos = pos, with_labels = False, node_size = 0)

#Plot it on the screen
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply search for it using the [edge selector](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html).

There's no built-in selector (afaik) but you can create a helper function that loops through the edges and returns your list.

```
def filter_edges(value):
   edge_list = []
   for u,v,s in G.edges(data='state'):
      if s == value:
          edge_list.append((u,v))

   return edge_list
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But unfortunately, this won't solve my problem.
I just have to either be able to pick an edge of all the edges in G randomly, or be able to put all the edges in a list, randomly permutate them and then go through this list edge by edge and change their states accordingly.
I haven't found a way to get solution 1 to work and the problem with the second solution is that I am not allowed to change the data dict entries, only when working with `G.edges`.

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading your error, I don't think your error is related to randomly picking edges.  Instead, you are incorrectly trying to assign the state values.

`ed[10][2]` returns the whole edge (presumably a dict).  It'd be helpful to include the output when you just run `ed[10][2]`.

You can't assign an int to that.  You likely want to do `ed[10][2]['state'] = 1`